# cannot find a variable in .g.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

There are 2 files here..**data_model.dart** and **data_model.g.dart**..so I initialized a variable called "id" in my .dart file but I couldn't see that variable in .g.dart file.

This is my code.
I initialized id variable in

```
class StudentModel {
@HiveField(0)
final int? id;

@HiveField(1)
final String name;

@HiveField(2)
final String age;
```

but I'm not able to see this variable in my .g.dart file

```
return StudentModel(
      name: fields[0] as String,
      age: fields[1] as String,
```

Full code here

**data_model.dart**

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'data_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class StudentModel {
@HiveField(0)
final int? id;

@HiveField(1)
final String name;

@HiveField(2)
final String age;

StudentModel({required this.name, required this.age, this.id}); //constructor
}
```

**data_model.g.dart**

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'data_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class StudentModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<StudentModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  StudentModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return StudentModel(
      name: fields[0] as String,
      age: fields[1] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, StudentModel obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.age);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is StudentModelAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

Thank you in advance :) <3

Comment: Did you try re-running the generator again after you initialized the variable "id"?

Comment: @Tim yes i restarted it and still its not changing..let me try again..no its not showing still